# How to search array using UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar, viewcontroller

I have multiple `ViewControllers` all linked to an initial `ViewController`. Each of the extra `ViewControllers` acts as a 'tennis court', with `player1` and `player2`'s names entered into `UITextFields`, and then stored in an array.

Is it possible, using a `UISearchBar` on the initial `ViewController`, to search the name of a player stored in one of the various variables, and then for that result to link to the `ViewController` within which it appears?

Answer (score 1):

Recall **MVC**.

You never store your data or model in any viewControllers. You store them in a model that may be an array, dictionary, or plist or even a database.

So you need to search from the model using your UISearchBar.

**If you show your code, we can correct them.*

Comment: I don't understand, what is a 'model' in this context?